# Defining multiple streams and adding fields to each of them in PyroCMS

Tags: php, pyrocms

I am new to PyroCMS and am willing to build a Job Site wherein there'll be 2 main users namely, Employers and Job Seekers. In order to allow them to register on the site, I'm using the Streams API from PyroCMS to build the forms. These users will be part of 2 different modules namely the **Employer** module and the **Job Seeker** module.

In the details.php file, under the install() function, I want to create multiple streams(database tables). The following code helps us to add a stream:

```
$this->streams->streams->add_stream();
```

The following code then helps us to define the fields to be added to the stream:

```
$this->streams->fields->add_fields($fields);
```

My concern is how do I add multiple streams like the above ones and add fields to each of them? In other words, how would the syntax

```
$this->streams->fields->add_fields($fields);
```

know which stream to add the fields to?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Fields Driver](http://docs.pyrocms.com/2.1/manual/index.php/developers/tools/streams-api/fields-driver) documentation for the Streams API. Fields and streams are separate entities, with no required association between the two. When adding a field you can assign it to a stream like this:

```
$field = array(
'name'          => 'Question',
'slug'          => 'question',
'namespace'     => 'streams_sample',
'type'          => 'text',
'extra'         => array('max_length' => 200),
'assign'        => 'STREAM_SLUG_GOES_HERE',
'title_column'  => true,
'required'      => true,
'unique'        => true
);

$this->streams->fields->add_field($field);
```

Or you can create the streams and fields separately, and then assign each field to a stream like this:

```
$this->streams->fields->assign_field('streams_sample', 'STREAM_SLUG_GOES_HERE', 'question', array('required' => true));
```

All this talk of fields and streams makes me want to go outside...

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple streams like this example.

```
    // Add banners streams
    if ( ! $this->streams->streams->add_stream(lang('banner:banners'), 'banners', 'banner', 'banner_', null)) return false;

    // Add groups streams
    if ( ! $this->streams->streams->add_stream(lang('banner:groups'), 'groups', 'banner', 'banner_', null)) return false;

    // Add some fields
    $fields = array(
    // BANNERS
        array(
            'name' => 'Banner Title',
            'slug' => 'banner_title',
            'namespace' => 'banner',
            'assign' => 'banners',
            'type' => 'text',
            'extra' => array('max_length' => 200),
            'title_column' => true,
            'required' => true,
            'unique' => true
        ),
    // GROUPS
        array(
            'name' => 'Group Title',
            'slug' => 'group_title',
            'namespace' => 'banner',
            'assign' => 'groups',
            'type' => 'text',
            'extra' => array('max_length' => 200),
            'title_column' => true,
            'required' => true,
            'unique' => true
        )
);

    $this->streams->fields->add_fields($fields);
```

Comment: What if the stream existed already and I just wanted to add a custom module on it as a sub menu?